# Using $all to match values inside an array inside of another array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have the following mongo document structure

```
  "search": [
    [
      "keyword",
      "match"
    ],
    [
      "testing",
      "something",
      "serious"
    ]
]
```

I want to find documents where the array of keywords inside of the array match an `$all` query.

E.g if search had only 1 level I would do

```
{'search': {'$all': ['keyword','match']}}
```

I've tried using:

```
{'search': {'$elemMatch': {'$all': ['keyword','match']}}}
```

But I get no results.

Comment: What's an $all query?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue you were facing?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah Nope, afraid not.

Comment: Can you include a full document from your collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the array of keywords in advance and you want to match a document that contains that array inside the `search` array, you can just use a simple query as follows.

```
db.collection.find({"search": ["keyword", "match"]});
```

That should return your sample document. On the other hand, if the array is not completely contained by an element inside `search`, it will not return anything. For example the following query will not return your sample document.

```
db.collection.find({"search": ["keyword", "match", "testing"]});
```

Comment: That doesn't work for my use case. I'm using $all so that I can use your second example.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand the issue you are facing. Do you want the document to match if the array it contains is a subset of the array you give it? Or vice versa?